# Beta version of Android apps available in Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, beta, developer-console

I understand Google randomly checks Apps for their compliance with its policies, in case of non-compliance, such apps are removed from Google Play. Can we do something so that before the app is available to common users, one can figure out App's compliance with the policies?

Natural question is, are the Beta version Apps subjected to Google compliance checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Google sent me an e-mail about "unauthorized use of copyrighted content in your promotional screenshots". The app is only available to beta-testers and is just a little fun-project which user base is very limited (it's just my girlfriend and me). To avoid creating some promotional material I simply uploaded a picture of myself as promotional material because adding some promotional material is required.

This triggered the google auto-check after my app was in the store for around 180 days. The e-mail contains a few information how to deal with it:

> After review, xxx, has been removed from Google Play because of an unauthorized use of copyrighted content in your promotional screenshots. This app won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.
>
> Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> Remove any content owned by a third party from your promotional
>   screenshots.
>
> Read through the [Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content](https://play.google.com/about/spam.html#impersonation-intellectual-property:unauthorized-use-of-copyrighted-content)
>   article for more details and examples.
>
> Make sure your app is compliant with the [Impersonation and Intellectual Property policy](https://play.google.com/about/spam.html#impersonation-intellectual-property) and all other
>   policies listed in the [Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html). Remember that
>   additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues
>   with your apps.
>
> Sign in to your Developer Console and submit your app.
>   If approved, your app will again be available with all installs,
>   ratings, and reviews intact.
>
> What if I have permission to use the content?
>
> [Contact our support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2993242) to provide a justification for its use.
>   Justification may include providing proof that you are authorized to
>   use the content in your app or some other legal justification.
>
> If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this removal may have been in
>   error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my
>   colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.

I am not aware of any checks you can do before you publish your app. But yes, Beta-Versions are actually affected and will be scanned!

Comment: So, you mean your Beta version of App was around 180 days in Google play before Google scanned it for compliance check?

Comment: Yep! Perhaps they modified the automatic compliance check and rescanned it but it was in beta for almost half a year.

Comment: Just to confirm, when the scanning took place, your App was in Beta version correct?

Comment: It never went public so yes, the scanning took place while the app was in beta!

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. I am accepting your answer :)

Comment: I'll be able to award the bounty after 20 hrs!